# It's possible to disable incoming call for Facetime programmatically? - Mac OSX

Tags: macos, facetime

I am building an app for macosx and I need to disable the incoming call for Facetime.
It's possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general - you shouldn't do this.

If you really wanted to do it, you could consider the following:

You could insert `pf` rules to firewall the computer such that Facetime connections cannot get through - you would risk blocking other types of Apple push notifications, etc. at the same time.

Alternatively you could stop the processes from running that process incoming notifications and calls, such as apsd and perhaps apsd-ft if applicable.

Yet again, I wouldn't recommend doing any of the above. It certainly won't be possible for an App Store sandboxed app to do this. I would reconsider why you feel the need to block Facetime calls in the first place.